# Laravel show a "Please verify your phone number" notice on any page until verified

Tags: laravel

On the website I'm working at the moment, users that register can add the phone number as optional.
When they add/change the phone number I send them a notification with a 4 digit code asking them to verify the phone number.

In the user model then I have this two fields:

```
$user->phone_verification_code
$user->phone_verified_at
```

When the user add the phone number I set the phone_verification_code and empty the phone_verified_at field.

```
$verificationCode  = mt_rand(1000, 9000);
$user->phone_verification_code = $verificationCode;
$user->phone_verified_at = null;
```

I'm looking for a way to show to the logged user that haven't yet verified the phone number a notification on any page.

I will check with this condition and flash to the session this message:

```
if (!empty($user->phone_verification_code)&& empty($user->phone_verified_at)){
    session()->flash('warning', 'Please verify your phone number');
}
```

Where is the best place to check if the user has verified the phone number since I want to show flash the message on any page until verified?

I solved thanks to Mohammad adding the condition in a Middleware like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class EnsurePhoneIsVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ($request->user()->isMember()) {

            if (
                !empty($request->user()->profile->phone_verification_code)
                && empty($request->user()->profile->phone_verified_at))
            {
                session()->flash('warning', 'Please verify your phone number');
            }

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a middleware called MobileVerificationMiddleware and check this and set data in config

```
config('user_is_verified', true or false);
```

in blade you can use `@if(config('user_is_verified'))`

Comment: Thank you, I added my condition in a middleware and flash the message from there.